# How to create a model to pass generics

Tags: java, model

I want to create a model class which has two parameters; first is String and second param is an Object which is determined at the runtime. For e.g.

```
public class A{
    String someStringVar;
    SomeObjectDeterminedAtRuntime someObjectDeterminedAtRuntime;
}
```

Can I do it like:

```
Object object; //to pass any type of object
```

Or is there any sort of better way with generic classes to do that? P.S. I have getters and setters method too which I did not include here.

Comment: Would be better to use `Object` itself rather than generics and complicate the model.

Comment: What are you asking? Yes, you can pass an `Object` as a parameter to a class constructor...

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a simple class with one generic parameter?

```
public class A<T> {
    private final String a;
    private final T t;

    A(String a, T t) {
        this.a = a;
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```